# Eclipse RCP Plugin.xml Command binding enablement with a selection count of more than 1

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to enable this command when 2 or more elements are selected. Here`s a snippet of my plugin.xml:

```
<binding
  commandId="com.stackoverflow.commands.myCommand"
  rank="100">
 <enablement>
  <and>
   <count
    value="2">
   </count>
  </and>
 </enablement>
</binding>
```

This obviously only works when exactly 2 elements are selected. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<not>` with `<or>` like that:

```
<binding
    commandId="com.stackoverflow.commands.myCommand"
    rank="100">
<enablement>
<not>
    <or>
        <count value="0" />   
        <count value="1" />
    </or>
</not>
</enablement>
```

I haven't tried it, but it should works.